# Trivial, short, and simple android unit tests throwing NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, junit

I have an itty-bitty Android project I cobbled together to learn about Android unit and instrumented testing. I use the dog.ceo API to get a random image of a dog. The program itself works as it should. However, whenever I run or debug my unit tests, I get NullPointerExceptions on all of them, with the following stack trace for each:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.jmarkman.dog.DogAPI.getDogURL(DogAPI.java:27)
    at com.jmarkman.dog.DogAPITest.getJSON(DogAPITest.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)
```

This is my main (only) activity: https://gist.github.com/jmarkman/733b0a1cbeb41a1c5733c0c715e4606b

This is my class for interacting with the dog.ceo API. It's a regular old Java class without any kind of design pattern applied to it: https://gist.github.com/jmarkman/c38546d99b0ca06099175a8da68d76b6

```
package com.jmarkman.dog;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DogAPI
{
    private final String DOG_API_URL = "https://dog.ceo/api";

    public DogAPI() { }

    public URL getDogURL()
    {
        URL url = null;

        Uri uri = Uri.parse(DOG_API_URL).buildUpon()
                .appendPath("breeds")
                .appendPath("image")
                .appendPath("random")
                .build();

        try
        {
            url = new URL(uri.toString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return url;
    }

    public URL getDogURL(String breed, boolean random)
    {
        URL url = null;
        Uri uri;

        if (random)
        {
            uri = Uri.parse(DOG_API_URL).buildUpon()
                    .appendPath("breed")
                    .appendPath(breed)
                    .appendPath("images")
                    .appendPath("random")
                    .build();
        }
        else
        {
            uri = Uri.parse(DOG_API_URL).buildUpon()
                    .appendPath("breed")
                    .appendPath(breed)
                    .appendPath("images")
                    .build();
        }

        try
        {
            url = new URL(uri.toString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return url;
    }

    public String getJSON(URL url) throws IOException
    {
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(stream);
        scanner.useDelimiter("\\A");

        boolean hasData = scanner.hasNext();

        try
        {
            if (hasData)
            {
                return scanner.next();
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("Error", e.toString());
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }

    public Uri getImage(String json)
    {
        final String MESSAGE = "message";
        Random random = new Random();
        Uri imageURL = null;

        try
        {
            JSONObject imageObj = new JSONObject(json);
            Object imageMsg = imageObj.get(MESSAGE);
            if (imageMsg instanceof String)
                imageURL = Uri.parse(imageMsg.toString());
            else if (imageMsg instanceof JSONArray)
            {
                int urlIndex = random.nextInt(((JSONArray) imageMsg).length() + 1);
                imageURL = Uri.parse(((JSONArray) imageMsg).getString(urlIndex));
            }
        }
        catch (JSONException jse)
        {
            jse.printStackTrace();
        }

        return imageURL;
    }
}
```

The instrumented tests run without issue. My unit tests aren't overly complicated; they're even shorter than the ones in the Pluralsight course I watched about Android testing. The following is every line in my test file, verbatim:

```
package com.jmarkman.dog;

import android.net.Uri;
import org.junit.Test;
import java.net.URL;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class DogAPITest {
    @Test
    public void getDogURL() throws Exception
    {
        DogAPI dog = new DogAPI();
        String expectedURL = "https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random";
        String actualURL = dog.getDogURL().toString();

        assertEquals(expectedURL, actualURL);
    }

    @Test
    public void getDogURLForBreed() throws Exception
    {
        DogAPI dog = new DogAPI();
        String url = dog.getDogURL("corgi", true).toString();

        assertEquals("https://dog.ceo/api/breed/corgi/images/random", url);

    }

    @Test
    public void getJSON() throws Exception
    {
        DogAPI dog = new DogAPI();
        URL url = dog.getDogURL();
        String returnJSON = dog.getJSON(url);

        assertNotNull(returnJSON);
    }

    @Test
    public void getImage() throws Exception
    {
        DogAPI dog = new DogAPI();
        URL url = dog.getDogURL();
        String returnJSON = dog.getJSON(url);

        Uri uri = dog.getImage(returnJSON);

        assertNotNull(uri);
    }
}
```

I have unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true in my build.gradle file. I've gone to the build menu and cleaned and rebuilt the project. Yes, I read the "What is a NullPointerException" question already. What am I missing?

Comment: What does your `DogAPI` class look like?

Comment: (I'm aware it's in the Github link, but best to include relevant code here in case GitHub ever goes down)

Comment: Sure, I can put the `DogAPI` class itself in the question, was afraid it would run on and be too large.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `DogAPI` class (specifically the `getDogURL()` method) makes use of `android.net.Uri.parse()`, which is in a class specific to the Android framework. Android-specific classes are not available within local JUnit tests, and are present as just stubs if you enable `unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true`. From [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html):

> If you run a test that calls an API from the Android SDK that you do not mock, you'll receive an error that says this method is not mocked. That's because the `android.jar` file used to run unit tests does not contain any actual code (those APIs are provided only by the Android system image on a device).

You've got two options. First is to use the [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/) testing library, which provides functional versions of Android classes for running in local JUnit tests. This would only need the addition of `@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)` at the top of your test.

Alternatively, use a different Uri parser, such as [`java.net.URL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html), which coincidentally also has a [`toURI()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#toURI--) method.

Comment: Ah, I see. Two questions: Is it common for even minimal testing to make use of an external testing library like Robolectric or Mockito? Is it as obvious as I think it is to identify whether or not I'll run into this issue in the future by checking to see if I'm importing anything starting with android, like my case here with `android.net.Uri`?

Comment: Firstly, yes. Mockito is a very handy library, especially when testing classes that have a large chain of dependencies. It allows you to provide expected return values from other classes, allowing you to test your target class purely in isolation.

Comment: Secondly, also yes. If it's a class from the `android.*` package, you won't have a live class available to you in local JUnit tests. For simpler stuff I'd recommend Robolectric, for more advanced stuff it's probably better just to run it as an `androidTest` on a device or emulator. Whatever saves you more time in the long run.